# Why does NOT my certificate chain contain the CA root certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, certificate

I simulate a CA on a centos7 host(azcn-gs1-nginx2), and use the CA to sign a certificate for a server(azcn-gs1-nginx1).

Below are what I do:

1. On CA azcn-gs1-nginx1, generate key

```
cd /etc/pki/CA/private/
openssl  genrsa -aes128 -out  testCA.key 2048
```

2. Generate CA certificate

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1825 -key /etc/pki/CA/private/testCA.key -out  /etc/pki/CA/certs/testCA.crt
```

3. On the server azcn-gs1-nginx2, generate private key and certificate sign request.

```
openssl  genrsa  -out  /etc/pki/tls/private/newServer.key 1024
openssl  req -new  -key  /etc/pki/tls/private/newServer.key  -out  /etc/pki/tls/newServer.csr
```

4. Copy newServer.csr to CA host for signing.

```
scp /etc/pki/tls/newServer.csr   root@azcn-gs1-nginx2:~/newServer.csr
```

5. On CA host, sign the newServer.csr, and copy back the newServer.crt
   to server azcn-gs1-nginx2.

```
openssl x509 -req  -in ./newServer.csr   -CA /etc/pki/CA/certs/testCA.crt  -CAkey /etc/pki/CA/private/testCA.key  -CAcreateserial  -out newServer.crt  -days 1461
scp newServer.crt root@azcn-gs1-nginx2:/etc/pki/tls/certs/newServer.crt
```

6. Server azcn-gs1-nginx2 is a reverse proxy for a webservice. I configure the newServer.key and newServer.crt in Nginx for https.

```
        ssl_certificate         /etc/pki/tls/certs/newServer_1.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/pki/tls/private/newServer.key;
```

7. I am on another Ubuntu host. I import the CA's certificate testCA.crt into Ubuntu truststore, as below:

```
cp testCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
update-ca-certificates
```

8. The Ubuntu's built-in browser is firefox. I also import testCA.crt
   into firefox's truststore. Please see attached pic.

[image]

I open firefox browser and visit web server by https. Expected result is it can directly open webpage without security warning.

Unfortunately, it gives warning of "Your connection is not secure.....".

[image]

and, looks like the certificate only contains the certificate itself. It doesn't not contain CA's certificate.

[image]

Why this happen? How can I get a signed certificate with the CA's certificate in Chain?
Thanks & regards,
Jie

Comment: Firefox does not use this trust store but comes with its own. Use Firefox settings instead  to add a trusted CA into firefox.

Comment: @Steffen: they did, see image 1. OP: Your image 2 is on Ubuntu and does NOT show the root missing, it shows a different error: the domain name in the cert (that you put as Common Name in the CSR) differs from the domain name you tried to connect to (in the URL). You need to either make the CSR-and-cert the same as the URL, or vice versa, or make the cert a wildcard (one level only). Your image 3 shows the root missing on some other browser or software on _Windows_ but not Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, yeah, you're right. The pics are other issue. The certificate chain is very simple, just concatenating 2 .crt files into single one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments.
That's right.

Actually, it is very simple. The 2 .crt files of CA and server can be concatenated into one .crt. Then the certificate chain is a whole.

Right, the pictures of 2 and 3 are other problems.

Thanks,
Jie